# Find the number of bit strings which start with four zeroes and end with three ones

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

Count the number of bit strings that start with four $0$'s or end with three $1$'s if the length of the bit string is:

1. $7$
2. $4$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. For 4 the only options are "0000" , "0111" and "1111".
2. For 7 use inclusion exclusion principle, with event $A$ as getting four zeros in front and event $B$ as 3 one's in the end. So answer will come out to be $2^3+2^4-1$.

In general for lengths $n>=7$ the answer would be $2^{n-4}+2^{n-3}-2^{n-7}$.

Comment: 2. is even simpler to count than using the inclusion exclusion principle. A matching string either starts with 0000 or not. If it doesn't it must end in 111. There are $2^3$ of the first, $2^4-1$ of the second.

Comment: yeah you are correct

Comment: how come you subtract 1?

Comment: because the string "0000111" gets counted twice once in event A and once in B , 1 is the cardinality of intersection of A and B and thus is subtracted

Comment: @sasha if the length is 8 would the answer be $2^4+2^5-1?$

Comment: it would be 2^5+2^4-2

Comment: @Csci319 see my edit

Comment: yeah thanks a lot